# TensorFlow : lstm dropout implementation, shape problems

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on an prediction project using lstm model in TensorFlow.
The structure of the implementation worked, however, got a bad result which the accuracy of testing set was only 0.5. Thus, I have searched whether there exists some tricks of training a lstm-based model. Then I got "adding dropout".

However, following the tutorial by others, some errors occur.

Here's the original version and it worked :

```
def lstmModel(x, weights, biases):
    x = tf.unstack(x, time_step, 1)

    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden, state_is_tuple=True, forget_bias=1)
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn (lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)rnn.static_rnn)

    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

and after changing to below, it occurs an error :

> ***ValueError: Shape (90, ?) must have rank at least 3***

```
def lstmModel(x, weights, biases):
    x = tf.unstack(x, time_step, 1)

    lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_hidden, state_is_tuple=True, forget_bias=1)
    lstm_dropout = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)
    lstm_layers = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout]* 3)
    outputs, states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_layers, x, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

I'm confused if my shape of input data went wrong.
Before entering this function, the input `x` is in the shape `(batch_size, time_step, data_size)`

```
batch_size = 30 
time_step = 4 #read 4 words 
data_size = 80 # total 80 words, each is in np.shape of [1,80]
```

So, the input shape `x` each batch is `[30,4,80]`.
And the input word `x[0,0,80]` is followed by the word `x[0,1,80]`.
Does the design make sense ?

The whole implementation is actually modified by other tutorial and I also wonder what did the `tf.unstack()` actually do?

several problems above...
I have putted the code in [github](https://github.com/billy0059/LstmTest) with "worked version" and "failed version" mentioned above.
Only the mentioned function differs!
Please check,
thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: @Nicolas sorry for that, I have put it in the github... https://github.com/billy0059/LstmTest/tree/ed048f8e7393c6d25473d705bdeb0404c071ef5d

Answer (score 1):

Removing `tf.unstack` from the second example should help.

[`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) is used to break a tensor into a list of tensors. In your case, it will break `x` which is of size `(batch_size, time_step, data_size)` into a list of length `time_step` containing tensors of size `(batch_size, data_size)`.

This is needed for [`tf.nn.static_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/static_rnn) since it unfolds the rnn during graph creation so it needs a pre-specified number of step which is the length of the list coming from `tf.unstack`.

[`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn) is unfolded in each run so that it can do a variable number of steps, therefore it takes one tensor where dimension 0 is the `batch_size`, dimension 1 is the `time_step` and dimension 2 is the `data_size` (or the first two dimensions are reversed if `time_major` is `True`).

The error is due to `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` expecting a 3D tensor but each element in the supplied inputs list is 2D only due to `tf.unstack`.

tl;dr Use `tf.unstack` with `tf.nn.static_rnn` but never use it with `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn`.

Comment: Got it !
I have removed the tf.unstak() , but another error occur.. just put my code 
 with error message on github (ipython) ..  
https://github.com/billy0059/LstmTest/tree/ed048f8e7393c6d25473d705bdeb0404c071ef5d
.

Comment: the new error is "ValueError: Trying to share variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel, but specified shape (512, 1024) and found shape (346, 1024)."

Comment: You are getting this error because of this line: lstm_layers = rnn.MultiRNNCell([lstm_dropout]* 3), probably because you are using TF version 1.2 but got this example from earlier TF versions. See release notes for v1.2 where they explain how to write this line differently as a loop: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/RELEASE.md

Comment: @VS_FF Thanks! I think I got some ideas. But after revise, the shape error which is my biggest problem occurs again..  the error message this time is InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[3,90] labels_size=[30,90]
  [[Node: SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits = SoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape, Reshape_1)]]

Comment: Yes, that you are getting further down the road, as it seems that the shape for your labels is different from the shape of the output of the matmul operation that you are doing right after dynamic_rnn.

Comment: @VS_FF yes...  it seems '3' denotes the time_steps and '90' denotes the data length;  the '30', where in the labels_size denotes the batch_size...   I was thinking about reshape but ...  how should I reshape and which to reshape...

Comment: Simple reshape won't help you as these are clearly incompatible shapes. You need to understand clearly what you are doing -- is this a one-to-many network where you have N steps in input and just one label? or you have a label for each step in input (i.e. Y is just X shifted by some time steps)? Fixing this really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @VS_FF Thanks, I am trying to achieve the a model where I input 3 data with length 80, and output the just one data label !  and it seems the matmul right after the dynamic_rnn worked well, so I am going though the following code now.

Comment: The key thing to keep in mind here is that the output of dynamic_rnn would contain one dimension that you technically don't have elsewhere in your data -- the Cell Size of your LSTMCell. So the point of that matmul operation is to morph that dimension into the number of classes that your data has.